# string representation of dictionary without quotes in values

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to create a string that can be evaluated to a dictionary such as:

```
'{"key1": val1, "key2": val2}'
```

I first tried:

```py
str({key: "val%d" % i for i, key in enumerate(args)})
```

This mostly works except instead of `val1` I get `'val1'`. I might be able to do something with a for loop, but that felt awkward. Is there a better way of doing this?

Unfortunately I can't just pickle the dictionary, it needs to be a valid Python dictionary.

Comment: `val1` is a string in a dictionary for which you're getting a string representation. It will always have quotes, unless you do some manual work. 

I get that it doesn't seem elegant, and you're right, it isn't. But the constraints you have here are strange, maybe there's a way to reframe the larger problem so that you don't need to eval a dict from a string? It would help to know the larger context.

Comment: Does `repr(args)` work for you?

Comment: `repr` and `str` do mostly the same thing for  dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty, but accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
args = ["key1", "key2"]

your_attempt = str({key: "val%d" % i for i, key in enumerate(args)})
# outputs: "{'key2': 'val1', 'key1': 'val0'}"

your_attempt.replace("': '","': ").replace("', '",", '").replace("'}","}")
# outputs: "{'key2': val1, 'key1': val0}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval()` if this is what you are after:

```py
val1 = "one"
val2 = "two"
test = '{"key1": val1, "key2": val2}'
test_dict = eval(test)
print(test_dict)
# {'key1': 'one', 'key2': 'two'}
```

Comment: I must have worded my question poorly. I want to construct a string like: `'{"key1": val1, "key2": val2}'` not turn one into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of standardization, I would suggest using the [builtin json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to encode and decode your info strings.

```
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
```

```
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

The `json` module plays nice with request, pickle, etc. and can help you avoid headache and mistakes by implementing the formatting protocols for you.